# Django form is not showing up

Tags: python, html, django, forms, function

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms


class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    from_ = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import EmailForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, "base.html")

def emailSender(request):
    form = EmailForm()
    return render(request, "base.html", {"form" : form})
```

And finally here is my html template

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
        <label class="form-label" for="from">From:</label>
        {{ form.from_ }}
    </div>
```

Any of my `{{ form }}` does not work. When I check the inspect tab they both are not created so I think this isn't some css problems here.

Comment: you are writing a python language i do not think that in python there is `;` .

Comment: Python does allow semicolon statement terminator. `a=1; b=2;` is valid python. However, it's considered bad style. The Pythonic way for this is `a, b = 1, 2`

Comment: Even when I removed semicolons , it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Tried the form code in shell , seems to be working ,try the following edits:

1. use a clear name to the field in **forms.py**

```py
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
```

2. Fix the html template (don't forget to close the form, I suppose you're taking proper care of other html tags: html, head, body, ...)

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I literally copied your code and created new project just to test it, and it still does not work. I don't know what am I doing wrong.